# mean, variance and entropy from histogram

Tags: python, opencv

I want to learn to manage histograms. Since now, I know how to obtain it using `cv2.calcHist()` and plot it with the `matplotlib` library and how compare two histograms using `cv2.compareHist()` too.

Now, I want to know how to extract some characteristics as mean, variance, normalised variance and entropy. Is this possible? I'm reading about this concept but I can't find how to do it.

This is how I'm comparing it:

```
HIST_METHODS = {
    "Correlation": cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL,
    "Chi-Squared": cv2.HISTCMP_CHISQR,
    "Intersection": cv2.HISTCMP_INTERSECT,
      "Hellinger": cv2.HISTCMP_BHATTACHARYYA
}
HIST_COLORS = ('b','g','r')

for key, value in HIST_METHODS.items():
    results = []
    for i, col in enumerate(color):
        hist1 = cv2.calcHist([img1],[i],None,[256],[0,256], accumulate = False)
        hist2 = cv2.calcHist([img2],[i],None,[256],[0,256], accumulate = False)
        res = cv2.compareHist(hist1, hist2, cv2.HISTCMP_CORREL)
        results.append(res)
```

PD: I'm using `OpenCV` right now, but if I have to use `numpy` or other library it won't be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get those statistics from Python/OpenCV.

References: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# read image
img = cv2.imread('lena.jpg')
h, w = img.shape[:2]
tot = h * w

# convert to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# calculate histogram
hist = cv2.calcHist([gray], [0], None, [256], [0, 256])

# view results
plt.hist(gray.ravel(), 256, [0,256], color='gray')
plt.show()

# get mean from image
imean = np.mean(gray)
print('image mean:', imean)

# get variance from image
# variance = mean of square of image - square of mean of image
grayf = gray.astype(np.float32)
grayf2 = grayf * grayf
imeanf2 = np.mean(grayf2)
ivar = imeanf2 - imean**2
istd = math.sqrt(ivar)
print('image variance and std:', ivar, istd)

# get mean from histogram
# i=graylevel and hist[i]=count
# mean = sum(hist[i]*i) / sum(hist[i]) = sum(i*hist[i]) / total pixels
sum = 0
for i in range (0,256):
    sum = sum + i*hist[i][0]
mean = sum/tot
print('histogram mean:', mean)

# get variance from histogram
# var = sum( hist[i]*(i-mean)**2 ) / total pixels
# hist[i][0] converts element of 1D array hist[i] to non-array numerical value
sum = 0
for i in range (0,256):
    sum = sum + ((i - mean) * (i - mean))*hist[i][0]
var = sum/tot
std = math.sqrt(var)
print('histogram variance and std:', var, std)

# alternate variance from histogram
# var = (hist[i]*sum((i)**2) / total pixels) - mean**2
sum = 0
for i in range (0,256):
    sum = sum + (i*i)*hist[i][0]
var2 = sum/tot - mean*mean
std2 = math.sqrt(var2)
print('histogram variance2 and std2:', var2, std2)


# Normalize so that the image graylevels are in the range 0 to 255 by dividing each graylevel by 255

# Normalize mean
nmean = mean/255
print('normalized histogram mean:', nmean)

# Normalize variance
nvar = var/(255*255)
nstd = std/255
print('normalized histogram variance and std:', nvar, nstd)
print('')

# entropy = -sum(hist[i]/tot)*log(hist[i]/tot))
# where hist[i]/tot = probability
# note: log(0) = -inf, so skip empty bins
entropy = 0
bins = 0
for i in range (0,256):
    if hist[i][0] != 0:
        entropy = entropy - (hist[i][0]/tot)*math.log(hist[i][0]/tot)
        bins = bins + 1
print('entropy:', entropy)

# normalized entropy = entropy/max_entropy
# where max_entropy is for uniform distribution
# normalized entropy = entropy/log(number of occupied bins)
nentropy = entropy/math.log(bins)
print('normalized entropy:', nentropy)
```

Histogram:

[image]

Statistics:

```
image mean: 124.03196716308594
image variance and std: 2267.4168247801717 47.61740044122707

histogram mean: 124.03196716308594
histogram variance and std: 2267.41558881826 47.61738746317631
alt. histogram variance and std: 2267.4155888182577 47.61738746317628

normalized histogram mean: 0.486399871227788
normalized histogram variance and std: 0.034869905249031295 0.18673485279676982

entropy: 5.160699283864339
normalized entropy: 0.9600803702533665
```